# В чем преимущество Avalonia перед WPF и UWP?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonia

Про кроссплатформенность знаю, но интереснее именно в плане упрощения написания компонентов. При беглом осмотре увидел, что некоторых тэгов XAML (например, Run и Paragraph) нет, но есть упрощенная запись Row\ColumnDifinition, но это есть как минимум и у MAUI, CSS-like селекторы еще, хорошо. Из коробки нет даже WebView, GMap можно поставить в виде пакета, но готов решений не так много в чем же собственно большие преимущества?

Comment: Ни в чем больше. Ведь именно кросс и есть основное преимущество. А MAUI вообще не вышел и сравнивать можно будет только когда выйдет.

Comment: IMHO как и любой другой инструмент Avalonia необходим при определённых требованиях/ограничениях и т.д. И как уже написал vitidev главное его преимущество (и скорее всего единственное) кроссплатформенность. Во многом остальном боль при сопровождении и расширении.

Comment: WPF и UWP - разные штуки, каждая со своими фичами, можно еще сюда же Win App SDK приплести. Avalonia имеет одно преимущество - кросплатформенность.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 0):

Главное преимущество - кросплатформ - это, наверное, единственное, учитывая, что платформы сами по себе примерно равноценны (xaml based platforms).

Ещё можно отметить, что платформу поддерживают, в отличие от wpf. А winui, как приемник мертворожденного uwp пока ещё очень далек по функционалу от wpf.

Главный недостаток - это отсутствие хоть сколь-нибудь серьезной линейки компонент под нее. Если вам нужно слепить быстро приложение типо LoB, вы сразу встретитесь с отсутствием нужной функциональности в "изкоробочных" контролах.